# formula for integer less than 15

Tags: regex, google-forms

In one field I want to accept numbers that could be decimal figure for weight but it should not be over 15. Previously I had the following regex code:

```
[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

This is to be entered in Google Forms. In other words, all these numbers are OK:
0.05
1.5
2
3.56

But these are not ok:
2 kg
0
15.1
16

Comment: Are regular expressions the only tool available to you?

Comment: @KeithThompson: better to use an abacus.

Comment: @KeithThompson I used Google Forms default validation rule. It did it with no issues at all. I am not sure why I was hung up on regex but I am really surprised there is no solution in regex

Answer (score 0):

This should work for values 0 to 15

```
^((1[0-5])|([1-9]))?(\.\d*)?$
```

Comment: This will match 0, .2 and even just a single dot, which isn't what's being asked for

Comment: use ^((1[0-5])|(\d))?(\.\d+)?$ to fix the single dot, but what about the 0 and the .2? they are less than 15

Comment: The question specifies that 0 isn't supposed to be accepted

Comment: Although now it doesn't match values such as 0.05 as was desired. As Keith said, this becomes unnecessarily complicated with a regex and a different approach should be taken if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the input.